# Passing variable from response to header in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

First request for the JSON in response body which looks like this:

```
{"data":{"userId":"USR-0000000000000001","accessToken":"TKN-05TS53MFRVK2QYH2HMLD3J25WMH8IH6E767W","refreshToken":"RTK-88TLRIYE4YVJMWH2H4G0UQK83DVCWODFLX4X","expiresIn":"2018-03-16 20:14:00","tokenType":"bearer"}
```

I extract the value of the "accessToken" attribute using the 
"Regular Expression Extractor":
[regular expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PblWO.png)

Then I pass the "Authorization" variable to the header, this step i need to put accesstoken to get information on my profile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW2Ef.png)

But then showing me this response on the results tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuWhM.png)

and response showing

```
"{"error":{"errorCode":1001,"errorMessage":"Authentication failed"}}"
```

What i want is on the next request can sucessfully read the accesstoken. can somebody help if theres something wrong on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put in the Regular expression extractor the name of the created variable.

Replace in regular expression from `Authorization` to `accessToken` because it is the name of the variable created that you are using

Answer (score 2):

Json Exractor also used to exctract the json resonse value. here below images are helpful for extracting the value from json . storing it in the variable and using it for the header request.

[image: JsonExtractor Control]

[image: StoredVariable Used Http Header Request]

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation :) yas it seems i will using JSON Extractor instead of the Regular Expression Extractor :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change header value to `Bearer ${Authorization}`, as per [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-6.1.1) it should start with `Bearer` and header values MAY be case sensitive
2. It makes more sense to go for [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead of the Regular Expression Extractor, when it comes to [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data regular expressions. You should be able to extract the token value using simple [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query like:

   [image: JMeter JSON Extractor]

   More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: Thanks for the help and recomendation :) yas it seems i will using JSON Extractor instead of the Regular Expression Extractor :)